# fatal error openssl/opensslv.h : No such file or directory

Tags: centos7, linux-kernel

I'm trying to compile latest stable kernel version 5.2.13 on centos 7(kernel 3.10.0). In make bzImage step, I got following error. How can I sort it out?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was sorted out by install openssl development package with following command on centos 7.

> sudo yum install openssl-devel

Answer (score 0):

Third party kernel RPMs exist for EL, mainline stable or long term support.

One of the well known repos specializing in kernel  is [elrepo](https://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml). You don't have to use them, but they have been hacking on kernel packages for several years, their spec files might be useful.

Benefits of RPM packages include:

- automatically installing `BuildRequires` when built with a tool like mock
- installed the same way as your other packages